# User password don't work vsftpd server

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I created an user with:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/false testuser
```

Also I added in the vsftpd.user_list 'testuser' and changed the password with passwd.
After a restart of the vsftpd service I wanted to log on on the server but
I got the Error 530 (Login incorrect).
Why can 't I log on on the server? With the default user, who was created on the installation of the server, it works. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with an reinstall of vsftpd. Now the user works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in the past, in my case the problem was that `/bin/false` is not a shell. (Sorry, can't explain better, forgot the background. I think it had something to do with PAM.)

Many older tutorials recommend settings `/bin/false` as shell for no-login users, but the better choice is `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Try setting `/usr/sbin/nologin` as login shell for FTP users:

```
usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin USERNAME
```

Then try logging in again.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't work. Also as I set the user on /bin/true, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@lxg You were really close to did this.

I agree that  `/usr/sbin/nologin`  is not a shell because you didnt add it to `/etc/shells`. So if you append this line to shells file to looks like for example this:

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

That solves the problem.

Of course command to login as user you have to use

```
 usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin USERNAME
```

and match permissions of shared directory.

To roll back login possibility just use:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash USERNAME
```

BTW. Only this way works for me on Ubuntu 16.04.